# Upload python object to Google Cloud Storage without saving it to file

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-python

I am clipping images in Python 2.7 on Windows 10 and would like to send them to Google's Cloud Vision API. For images saved locally, I can send them using the google.cloud python module like this:

```
                blob.upload_from_filename(filename=path)
```

Documented [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage/blobs.html)

I would rather not save each crop to file, just to send the numpy arrays directly. I could change the numpy arrays to str objects and use

```
blob.upload_from_string()
```

but then Cloud Vision API would not be able to read them in my bucket. Is there any way to pipe from python to cloud storage bucket without wasting time/space saving them as an intermediate temporary object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not. I am sorry!

Comment: Note that Google Cloud Storage does allow uploading from a stream, but the gcloud python library doesn't currently support doing this. Both boto and github.com/google/apitools support uploading from a stream.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your numpy array to json and then

```
filename = "file_name_required on cloud"
json_object = [] # your array
```

and then do

```
blob = BUCKET.blob(filename)
blob.upload_from_string(data=json.dumps(json_object),content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).